# How the wildcard ** work within fnmatch?

Tags: ruby, wildcard, matching

I notice an surprising behavior of the `fnmatch` function of Ruby:

```
File.fnmatch('**.rb', 'main.rb')                    #=> true
File.fnmatch('**.rb', './main.rb')                  #=> false
```

As far as being explained in the [the Ruby reference](http://ruby-doc.org/core-1.9.3/File.html#fnmatch-method), `**` will:

> Matches directories recursively or files expansively.

So why doesn't it expands and matches `./main.rb`?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This behavior is actually [documented](http://ruby-doc.org/core-1.9.3/File.html#method-c-fnmatch), but it's easy to miss. Buried in the examples it says:

> wildcard doesn't match leading period by default.

To enable this behavior, you need to specify the **File::FNM_DOTMATCH** flag:

```
File.fnmatch('**.rb', './main.rb', File::FNM_DOTMATCH)
=> true
```